# Maven Glassfish Deploy then test

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I can't seem to figure out how to get my maven project to deploy then test, it will obviously fail if it is not running on the glassfish server with the test I want to run, can someone give me some documentation or an example on how best this would be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before by creating a separate module for testing in a multi-module maven project. Use the Cargo maven plugin to deploy to your appserver during the pre-integration-test execution phase and then use the maven-failsafe-plugin to bind the integration-test goal to the integration-test phase. Put your test classes into src/test/java and prefix all the test class names with IT. Here's a snippet from my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.deployment</groupId>
                    <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <type>remote</type>
                    <containerId>glassfish3x</containerId>
                </container>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>com.foo.example</groupId>
                        <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
                        <type>ear</type>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.hostname>${glassfish.host}</cargo.hostname>
                        <cargo.glassfish.adminPort>${glassfish.adminport}</cargo.glassfish.adminPort>
                        <cargo.remote.username>${glassfish.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password>${glassfish.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-cargo</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deployer-redeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I appreciate it, this is what I was looking for, feel free to vote my question back up, as I feel that it wasn't that poor of a question to have been voted down by whoever. and Thank you again.

Comment: By the way, this works with JUnit 4.10. Different versions of JUnit work slightly differently when defining what's an integration test and what's not.